# how to remove color code in /var/log/syslog?

Tags: python, linux, git-bash

im new here and idk this is right place to put a question, plz let me know if any rules to follow.

anyway, im facing issue like below.
as u can see from pic, there is color code or some code like "#033[0m" at the end.
[/var/log/syslog img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFx6O.png)

img 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFx6O.png

is anyone know how to remove this code and colorize it?

this is the code of format i made:
[log.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rW2.png)

img 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rW2.png

its able to colorize the code when i show logs by using tail -f function.
[tail -f /var/log/syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUFtP.png)

img 3 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUFtP.png

but not on vi /var/log/syslog :(

i tried to change type as euc-kr and ansi from default.
also added $EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off on rsyslog.conf.
and installed ccze tools for colorize but it takes too much times for showing syslog which i cant use..

so would anyone able to remove this issue?
thanks in advance!

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFx6O.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rW2.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUFtP.png
there is a captured pic in my write but i cant see from posted... hope everyone can see the pic or inform me to attach pic plz :(

Comment: What is adding the color code to your logs?

Comment: @stark what do u mean adding the color code to my log?